# Use AWS CodeStar Connections Info with CodeBuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-codestar

I'm using CodePipeline for my CI/CD process. Currently migrating from CodeCommit to a private GitHub repo, I want to keep automating my tag and release process.
The issue is that I'd need a personal token to do so. However, that being said, we do use CodeStar connection for the same repo. Now my question is, is it possible to extract the token provided in the connection for CodeBuild?

TIA

Comment: There is no way to extract it or rely on the CodeStar connection in CodeBuild yet. For CodeBuild you'll either need to use Personal Token or OAuth